# Error when redirect in controller phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a router scope like bellow

```
scope "/", PetSaasWeb do
   pipe_through :browser

   get "/", PageController, :index
   get "/home", PageController, :index
   get "/interface", PageController, :interface
   get "/profile", PageController, :profile
   get "/logout", PageControler, :logout

   # login
   get "/login", LoginController, :getLogin
   post "/login", LoginController, :doLogin
end
```

and in my PageController I have

```
def logout(conn, _params) do
  redirect(conn, to: "/login")
end
```

When I access "/logout" I met error

[image]

I am a newbie in elixir and Phoenix, please explain why this error happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get "/logout", PageControler, :logout
```

must be

```
get "/logout", PageController, :logout
```

you hava written wrong the controller part

If you read the error message carefully you will notice that it says *PageControler.init is not defined*, which means there is no such controller